# need Oracle query - get a list of differnet attributes from a column

Tags: sql, oracle

how can I get a list of all the attributes in a column. There are so many rows sorting them doesn't work as I'd have to go through every row and count each different attribute. I'm guessing there are around 10 - 20 different attributes but there are over 500000 rows - any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct column_value from table
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the different values in a column and a count on how often the value occurs:

```
select the_column, count(*)
from the_table
group by the_column;
```